# Most performant way to assign values from one array into nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given a collection (`users` in the snippet below) with sub-collections, and another collection (`organizations`) that contains properties I need merged into the sub-collection of `users`, what is the most performant way to do so?

The code below works, but nested iterations never feel that great to me.  Further, the production environment has hundreds / thousands of results, so performance is at least a consideration.

FYI, I'm leveraging the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library, and am aware some performance gain would be had from *not* using the library - however, I'm hoping someone can offer a more effective approach to the problem.

The code below looks up the name of the organization and then adds that name to the `users` array for use in other parts of the app.

(The data structure is from an API, and cannot be changed.)

```js
// organizations are actually fetched from an API via Observable.  Can change at any time.
const organizations = [{
    organization_id: 5,
    organization_name: 'Sample 1'
  },
  {
    organization_id: 6,
    organization_name: 'Sample 2'
  },
  {
    organization_id: 9,
    organization_name: 'Sample 3'
  },
  // etc...
];

// users are actually fetched from an API via Observable.  Can change at any time.
const users = [{
    user_name: 'User 1',
    organizations: [{
        organization_id: 9,
        organization_role: 'Limited'
      },
      {
        organization_id: 6,
        organization_role: 'Admin'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    user_name: 'User 2',
    organizations: [{
        organization_id: 5,
        organization_role: 'Limited'
      },
      {
        organization_id: 6,
        organization_role: 'Limited'
      }
    ]
  },
  // etc...
];


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  _.forEach(users, (user) => {
    _.forEach(user.organizations, (organization) => {
      organization.organization_name = _.get(_.find(organizations, ['organization_id', organization.organization_id]), 'organization_name', '?');
    });
  });
  console.log(users);
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since `organizations` is static, you could start by turning it into a map so that you can do instant lookups on it when inside each user, rather than iterating through all of them. That would allow you to remove the `_.find`.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst - Great suggestion, however  neither organizations nor users are static.  I've simplified, these are actually being fetched from an API, and are results of Observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `_.find()` is an O(n) operation (where n is the length of organizations const), and the forEach operations O(m * l) (m number of users, l average number of organisations for each user), the total operation is O(n * m * l). You can lower it to O(n + m * l) by first mapping the organisations, which is an O(n) operation (using `_.keyBy()` for example).

```js
// organizations are actually fetched from an API via Observable.  Can change at any time.
const organizations = [{"organization_id":5,"organization_name":"Sample 1"},{"organization_id":6,"organization_name":"Sample 2"},{"organization_id":9,"organization_name":"Sample 3"}];

// users are actually fetched from an API via Observable.  Can change at any time.
const users = [{"user_name":"User 1","organizations":[{"organization_id":9,"organization_role":"Limited"},{"organization_id":6,"organization_role":"Admin"}]},{"user_name":"User 2","organizations":[{"organization_id":5,"organization_role":"Limited"},{"organization_id":6,"organization_role":"Limited"}]}];


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const orgDict = _.keyBy(organizations, 'organization_id');
  _.forEach(users, (user) => {
    _.forEach(user.organizations, (organization) => {
      organization.organization_name = _.get(orgDict['organization_id'], 'organization_name', '?');
    });
  });
  console.log(users);
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```